# Hibernate upgrade - Changed default Constraint Naming Strategy

Tags: hibernate, foreign-keys, constraints, upgrade

After upgrading Hibernate version from 4.1.12.Final to 5.1.0.Final, we realized that the naming convention for the Foreign key constraints, automatically generated by Hibernate, got changed.

Foreign-key constraints generated by Hibernate4 :
    "fk9ad71e905f9bc6ca"
    "fk9ad71e90ab88f852"

Foreign-key constraints generated by Hibernate5 :
    "fkcaaxqultt51c7wraf5f4mq3xb"
    "fkggqbdp3uqmi0grv8kwcs5wc8a"

Was wandering if there is a way to explicitly specify the naming convention so that we don't have to drop and recreate the constraints (In production it is going to take hours due to a large dataset).

Hibernate many to many entity example:

```
@ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.MERGE)
@JoinTable(name = "GEO_ZONE_ZIP", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "GEO_ZONE_GEO_ZONE_ID"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ZIPSTATESET_ZIP_STATE_ID"))
public Set<ZipState> getZipStateSet() {
    return this.zipStateSet;
}
```

Hibernate configurations:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">

        <property name="dataSource" ref="${hibernate.datasource}"/>

        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>

                <!--
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.driver_class">${hibernate.jdbcdriver}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.url">${hibernate.connection.url}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.username">${hibernate.connection.username}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.password">${hibernate.connection.password}</prop>
                 -->

                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql"> ${hibernate.showsql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">${hibernate.formatsql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.use_sql_comments">${hibernate.sqlcomments}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>

                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
```

Will greatly appreciate any help,

Roman.

Comment: The same problem exists between hibernate 3 and hibernate 4. I'm trying to find a solution so that I don't have to generate the liquibase changelog by hand.

Comment: Have you solved the problem in the meantime?